# Rspec routing redirect test failed for wildcard and sub-domain routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, rspec-rails

config/routes.rb

```
    constraints server_name: Rails.configuration.env.sub_domain do
      get '*any' => redirect("https://example/fuga")
```

routing_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe "any routes should be redirected", type: :request do
  context "redirect" do
    it "success" do
      get "/example", headers: { "Host" => Rails.configuration.env.sub_domain }
      response.should redirect_to("https://example/fuga")
    end
  end
end
```

I run my test:

```
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/example
```

I can confirm that it redirects properly in my browser.
How do I get the test to do what I expect it to do?

Comment: Can you run and compare those two commands: 1. `rails runner "puts Rails.configuration.env.sub_domain"` and 2. `RAILS_ENV=test rails runner "puts Rails.configuration.env.sub_domain"`

Comment: Are you sure that setting the `Host` header has the effect you want? if it's a subdomain, isn't the `subdomain` constraint better? it's used in the docs https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

Comment: `host! Rails.configuration.env.sub_domai`worked as expected.